# ASP.net: insert statement and gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, code-behind, sql-insert

I have an error which I am not able to understand what mistake I am doing. Before going to problems, let me tell you: I have four tables which is

```
Tbl1
+----+----------+-----------+----------+
| ID | NAME     | ADDRESS   | SALARY   |
+----+----------+-----------+----------+
| C1 | Ramesh   | Ahmedabad |  2000.00 |
| C2 | Khilan   | Delhi     |  1500.00 |
| C3 | kaushik  | Kota      |  2000.00 |
| C4 | Chaitali | Mumbai    |  6500.00 |
| C5 | Hardik   | Bhopal    |  8500.00 |
| C6 | Komal    | MP        |  4500.00 |
| C7 | Muffy    | Indore    | 10000.00 |
+----+----------+-----------+----------+

Tbl2
+----+----------+-----------+
| ID | NAME     | ADDRESS   |   
+----+----------+-----------+
| S1 | Roy      | Kolkota   |
| S2 | Praveen  | Delhi     |
| S3 | Madhuri  | Kota      |
| S4 | Hema     | Mumbai    |
| S5 | Anu      | Mumbai    |
| S6 | Khushi   | MP        |
| S7 | Anjali   | Indore    |
+----+----------+-----------+

Tbl3
+----+----------+-----------+
| ID | NAME     | ADDRESS   |   
+----+----------+-----------+
| P1 | Mouse    | Delhi     |
| P2 | Camera   | Delhi     |
| P3 | Pen Drive| Ahmedabad |
| P4 | RAM’s    | Mumbai    |
| P5 | Keyboard | Mumbai    |
| P6 | HDMI’s   | MP        |
| P7 | Hard Disk| Indore    |
+----+----------+-----------+   

Tbl4
+----+-------+-----------+-----------+
| ID | ID    | ID        | Total Cost|
+----+-------+-----------+-----------+
| C1 | S1    | P1        |    2000   |
| C1 | S1    | P3        |    1500   |
| C2 | S2    | P4        |    1200   |
| C2 | S3    | P2        |    1800   |
| C4 | S5    | P1        |    1000   |
| C5 | S6    | P5        |    900    |
| C6 | S7    | P6        |    190    |
| C7 | S6    | P4        |    1900   |
+----+-------+-----------+-----------+
```

Problem 1: I was trying to insert a new row in the tbl2 but I am having an error it says that column name does not exist.

For instance I have added S8 Rakesh Banglore (this is under three different text boxes). It says column name S8, column name Rakesh, column name Banglore does not exist. Below is my code. Also what should I add to give message for duplicate data? Also if I add S11 or something it comes under S1 so what should I do to arrange the table?

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
<appSettings>

    <add key="SQLConn" value="Data Source=online database source;Initial Catalog=database name;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=username;Password=password" />
</appSettings>
    </configuration>
```

code behind

```
 protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection SqlConn = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlConn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SqlConn"].ToString();
        SqlConn.Open();
        string query1 = "insert into tbl2(id,name,address) values (" + txt_id.Text + ",'" + txt_name.Text + "','" + txt_address.Text + "')";

        cmd = new SqlCommand(query1, SqlConn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlConn.Close();
    }
```

I am having a error listed above with line "SqlConn.Open();".

Problem 2:

If I have a web form with a two text box name txt_CID.txt and txt_SID.txt. It shows tbl3 row in a grid view. I am confused how do I print this with code behind. Also I would like to learn how can I print it without code behind.

For example:

So, If I enter C1 S1 the result should be

```
| P1 | Mouse    | Delhi     |
| P3 | Pen Drive| Ahmedabad |
```

which should show me the result in grid view.

Comment: I have removed "AddWithValue" and updated what you advised in my program Now error is - An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Invalid column name 'S8'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem 1:**

Not very sure but I think you are missing single quotes when you are adding **txtAddress and txt_id** to the query.

Your query

```
string query1 = "insert into tbl2(id,name,address) values (" + txt_id.Text + ",'" + txt_name.Text + "'," + txt_address.Text + ")";
```

Should be changed to

```
string query1 = "insert into tbl2(id,name,address) values ('" + txt_id.Text + "','" + txt_name.Text + "','" + txt_address.Text + "')";
```

Also remove `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` lines.

**Problem 2:**

I think you just need to join Tbl3 and Tbl4 so the query will be something like the following.

Also I have assumed that the 3 ids in Tbl4 are ID_1, ID_2 and ID_3.

I have not tested it so there might be some syntax errors.

```
"SELECT T3.ID, T3.NAME, T3.ADDRESS
FROM TBL3 T3
INNER JOIN TBL4 T4
ON T3.ID = T4.ID_3
WHERE T4.ID_1 = '" +  txt_CID.txt + "' AND T4.ID_2 = '" + txtSID.txt + "'";
```

**Code to show data to gridview**

```
DataSet objDataSet = new DataSet();
SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection();

string query = "";//Your query here

SqlCommand objComm = new SqlCommand(query, objConn);

SqlDataAdapter objDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(objComm);

if (objConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    objConn.Open();
}

objDataAdapter.Fill(objDataSet, "YourTableName");

dataGridView1.DataSource = objDataSet;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for that I will try and let you know.

Comment: Doing my problem 2 but I have question for this how would I connect this to grid view to show the result?

Comment: Check my updated answer regarding showing result in gridview. As for your error, I think you are missing single quotes in query where you are appending txt_id.txt in your query. You need to have single quotes in place where you are appending txt_id and txtaddress both. Note the bold text in my answer.

Comment: string query ="SELECT T3.ID, T3.NAME, T3.ADDRESS FROM TBL3 T3 INNER JOIN TBL4 T4 ON T3.ID = T4.ID_3 WHERE T4.ID_1 = '" +  txt_CID.txt +  "' AND T4.ID_2 = '" + txtSID.txt + "'"; right?

Comment: Yes this should be the query to fetch records for the gridview.

Comment: [Error explanation for problem 2](http://s8.postimg.org/4du9b94dh/error2.png) please see this.

Comment: Typo error: 1. Its Line error 2. Type name space 3. "; expected"

Comment: String query error got resolved. Figuring out for other error.

Comment: Having problem for State and Open().

Comment: Error1:'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand' does not contain a definition for 'State' and no extension method 'State' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Error2: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand' does not contain a definition for 'Open' and no extension method 'Open' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: If you have copy-pasted my code then this error should not come else check if the object on which State and Open are called is of type SqlConnection. You must be calling it on type SqlCommand

Comment: My table name is tbl4 "objDataAdapter.Fill(objDataSet, "tbl4");" is it right? Also thanks it was typo error thats why it was showing error. but about tbl4 is it right?

Comment: I did copy pasted it.

Comment: You can give any name you want. It just gives a logical name to the datatable. Also if my answer was useful to you then please upvote and/or mark it as accepted. :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I copied your code there are no error except gridview is not displaying it when I run it.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1 :**

Change your query to something like this

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection SqlConn = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlConn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SqlConn"].ToString();
    SqlConn.Open();
    string query1 = "insert into tbl2(id,name,address) values (@id,@name,@address)";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(query1, SqlConn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txt_id.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txt_name.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txt_address.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlConn.Close();
}
```

Comment: I do know that but to get the values from the all text box it should be 'string query1 = "insert into tbl2(id,name,address) values (" + txt_id.Text + ",'" + txt_name.Text + "'," + txt_address.Text + ")";'

Comment: No, I am afraid you are wrong. You have already assigned the value of "txt_id" to "@id" and "txt_name" to "@name" and so on..

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Must declare the scalar variable "@id".

Comment: Please see the above code for more clarification. Added complete code.

Comment: Now It worked for problem 1. Now I am concentrating on problem 2.

Comment: May I ask how can sort the table for instance if I add S10 it comes under S1. So how can I add the data at the end of the table?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1 Solution :**

You had open SqlConn.Open(); two times it makes an error,

Remove one of the statement.

And Remove the below lines in your code

```
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txt_id.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txt_name.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txt_address.Text);
```

Finally,

You had missed out the single quote for address(txtaddress.Text) code solved,

```
        SqlConnection SqlConn = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlConn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SqlConn"].ToString();
        SqlConn.Open();
        string query1 = "insert into tbl2(id,name,address) values (" + txt_id.Text + ",'" + txt_name.Text + "','" + txt_address.Text + "')";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(query1, SqlConn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlConn.Close();
```

Comment: After getting your advise I did remove my "SqlConn.Open();" but still it gives me that error. Also I have updated my post related to "SqlConn.Open();"

Comment: Sure I will upload it in a min